# Is english.stackexchange aimed at professionals, or also at rookies?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm a a newbie on english.stackexchange. Is this site suitable only for people who are proficient in the English language, or also for those who trying to learn English in all levels?

I mean, can I ask every English language oriented question I face there, or should only high-level questions be asked?

Comment: Why don't you ask them? Also, are you aware of [Ell.se]?

Comment: @Catija no I wasn't aware untill now

Comment: Well, thanks for posting this instead of posting your question on ELU right away. +1 from me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

English.SE (People are comfy with calling it ELU) is for questions a native English speaker may ask or questions there are about topics that concern mostly native speakers. There's a good chance that learner questions belong to ELL.SE. See how ELL's different from ELU: [What is the difference between ELU and ELL?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell)

[Learners](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/problem-with-faq-elu-audience-experts-only-or-students-too) are still welcome on ELU, but the question you ask needs to be one that a native speaker would find interesting, and hence questions about **learning** English language go to ELL.

It's a common misconception that this means questions on ELL are basic and the ones on ELU are not, but that's wrong. You're required to do research and present us with it just like any other SE.

I don't want to sound harsh, but judging by your punctuation, your question isn't likely to be received well on ELU.

Answer (score 7):

On English Language and Usage there is an expectation of competence in the language.

However, there is also English Language Learners on which much more elementary questions are accepted. Also, there is an expectation that questions are being asked by those for whom English is not the first language.

I suggest you take the Site Tour of each and decide which suits you better.

Answer (score 6):

For help with basic English, your questions would probably be more welcomed at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). From the [ELL Tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour):

> English Language Learners Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for speakers of other languages learning English.

The [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) suggests that that these topics are within scope:

> - Word choice and usage
> - Grammar
> - Dialect differences
> - Spelling and punctuation
> - Practical problems you encounter while learning English

Contrasted with [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour):

> English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.

EL&U is for more serious, scholarly questions.